# Android studio isn`t showing layout properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I started learning java and then thought about working with Android Studio. I installed Android Studio in Ubuntu and this is what it shows me.
[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You only have a TextView on Layout which wrap_content sizes, change it to match_parent to let it take some space

Comment: By improper layout i mean the two split images of smartphone ,i mean,shouldn`t it look something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl2rV.png ,mine is not even showing hello world in the screen.

Comment: @DheemanKuaner Hey could you also post your XML layout.

Comment: That's not a AndroidStudio preview problem.. its your TextViews with improper constraints, add the XML as Gionne asked

Comment: @GionneLapuz here is the image of the xml file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1glFtFanXF60FoOVU16DUJJeQXmnK0cJj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem whenever I create a new project in Android Studio, what you have to do is go to the styles.xml file and change the following line:

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And replace it with:

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent = "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[image]

[Split screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIP9o.png)

Comment: The split screen persists though,do you have any suggestion about that ?

Comment: I Add to the answer a second image with the description of the button that should be used, this will allow you to change the type of view of the layout