# Views in the layout not visible in Design nor Blueprint (even for a Hello World app)

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm having a beginner's problem, blocking my progress, when starting from a scratch application (created with Empty Activity). The initial application builds and runs great showing the Hello World message, but the layout does not show the TextView in the Design nor Blueprint window at all.

If I try to add additional Views, they are also not shown in Design or Blueprint although they do appear properly in the Component Tree and in the Text tab. In the Blueprint, there is just one light blue pixel in the top left - it looks like the Views would be there with zero size. [image: Picture 1] If I click the View in the Component Tree, it shows small icons in the Blueprint but I am not able to drag them (no handles visible). [image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3: XML]

Android Studio version is 3.1.3, completely up to date, rebooted several times, made a full successful build, "Show Constraints" is on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get me moving forward. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem whenever I create a new project in Android Studio, what you have to do is go to the styles.xml file and change the following line:

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And replace it with:

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent = "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[image: styles.xml]

Chkec this link:

[Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291015/android-studio-isnt-showing-layout-properly/51291287#51291287)

Comment: Thanks a lot Milton, that helped!